# Removing box from custom made check boxes

Tags: css, wordpress, checkbox, styles

I've created custom styled checkboxes that looks like this:

[image]

What I want is to remove the boxes from the checkboxes and give the button a new color if clicked, like this:

[image]

How could this be done? With pure CSS?

**the generated html:**

```
<p>
    Huvudområden:
    <label><input class="{category: true}" type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="40" id="grade40">Musicerande</label>
    <label><input class="{category: true}" type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="42" id="grade42">Musikens sammanhang</label>
    <label><input class="{category: true}" type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="41" id="grade41">Musikens verktyg</label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use what's called a [checkbox hack](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/).

As you can see the trick is to hide the checkbox using this kind of positionning:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}
```

And you then use the `label` to toggle the checkbox!